# How to make the submit button not appear on form unless an option is selected from radios?

Tags: 7, forms

I have a form with three form elements:

1. `'#type' => 'radios'` element having two options (Yes or No),
2. `'#type' => 'submit'` &
3. `'#type' => 'checkbox'`

When the user lands on the form page, he should only see the `radios` element first and can see the `checkbox` & `submit` elements only if he selects an option from `radios` element.

Is there a Drupal way to do this using the Form API?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [#states](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#states) attribute in form api to hide submit button and check box

For Example

```
$form['email_canceled']['settings'] = array(
    '#type' => 'container',
    '#states' => array(

      // Hide the settings when the cancel notify checkbox is disabled.

      'invisible' => array(

       ':input[name="email_canceled_toggle"]' => array('checked' => FALSE),
      ),
    ),
  );
```